# CentOS Installing Blender. svn: E175002 Could not read file size

Tags: linux, svn, centos, blender

I'm trying to install Blender using [this](https://www.blender.org/manual/about/contribute/install/linux.html) guide from Blender.org.

However, when I get to the step of installing the repo, I am faced with the error message svn: E175002: REPORT of '/svnroot/bf-manual/!svn/me': Could not read chunk size: Secure connection truncated (https://svn.blender.org).

How do I resolve this issue? Also, what's wrong with just installing the tarball from blender.org rather than using the repo?

Comment: FYI, there's a **[blender.se]** site where the [blender.se] experts are.

Answer (score 1):

Your actually near the end of the manual under "About this manual" and are looking at the instructions for contributing to the manual itself - not blender.

If you go back to the top under "Getting Started" you will find [steps for installing blender](https://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/installing/introduction.html) which has a link to the [blender.org download page](https://builder.blender.org/download)